# Click icon button in the card component without clicking the whole card

Tags: reactjs, material-ui

I have a card component that is clickable, and it contains an icon button in the card, I want to be able to click the icon button without clicking the whole cardwith it.

Currently when the icon button is clicked, the ripple effect runs on the whole card, but I want to be able to click the icon button only and see no ripple effect, but when I click the main card, I see the ripple effect.

I added a codesandbox link having the code I used:
https://codesandbox.io/s/material-demo-forked-lbnbh?file=/demo.js

```
<Card className={classes.root}>
  <CardActionArea>
    <CardMedia className={classes.media} title="Con" />
    <CardContent>
      <IconButton aria-label="add to favorites">
        <AddBoxIcon style={{ fontSize: 50 }} />
      </IconButton>
    </CardContent>
  </CardActionArea>
</Card>
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If you want the click event of the child component fires and not propagate to the parent component use [`e.stopPropagation()`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/Event/stopPropagation).

Also if you want the propagation applied to ripple effect, make sure to attach the handler to the `onMouseDown` event instead of `onClick`. `onClick` event fires after the ripple effect is triggered so it doesn't work.

```
<IconButton>
  <AddBoxIcon onMouseDown={e => e.stopPropagation()} />
</IconButton>
```

### Live Demo

[image: Edit Material-UI Card Ripple]

Comment: Your Demo works when the ripple effect is disabled, but the problem is that I would like to see the ripple effect only when the card is clicked @NearHuscarl

Comment: Can you explain to me how you fixed it @NearHuscarl

Comment: Replace `onClick` with `onMouseDown`. `onClick` event seems to fire after the ripple effect is triggered so it doesn't work

Answer (score 0):

You need to put onClick on the IconButton.

```
const onIconClick =e=>{
console.log("In icon click")
}
```

```
<IconButton aria-label="add to favorites" onClick={onIconClick}>
        <AddBoxIcon style={{ fontSize: 50 }} />
      </IconButton>
```